# While Loop Inside For Loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

I expect the given code to output the answer : `1`. However the loop runs forever. I am trying to see if while loop works for such a case. The use of while loop is necessary for the solution.

```r
a = list(1,2,3,4)

for(i in a){
  while(i != 2){
    print(i)
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you need a `while` with `for` loop.  May be you just need `for(i in a) if(i < 2) print(i)`

Comment: @akrun I am trying to understand what can be done with while loop. Is it possible to use it in such a case to work?

Comment: With `while`, you may increment the index like `flag <- TRUE;
i <- 1;
while(flag) {
print(a[[i]]);


i <- i + 1;
if(a[[i]] == 2) {
 flag <- FALSE;
}` or use `break` statement

}

Comment: How is the answer supposed to be `1`? Are you trying to iterate over the list and print them until you reach `2`? Then it seems you need one loop, either `for` or `while`, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions that work with `while`.  The first one with a 'flag' set as TRUE, and the index as 1, based on the condition, set the 'flag' to FALSE

```
flag <- TRUE
i <- 1
while(flag) {
  print(a[[i]])
  i <- i + 1
  if(a[[i]] == 2) {
   flag <- FALSE
    }

 }
#[1] 1
```

Or we add a `break`

```
i <- 1
while(TRUE) {
  print(a[[i]])
  i <- i + 1
  if(a[[i]] == 2) {
    break
    }

  }
#[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `i` does not change inside the `while` loop, so you never advance to the next item in list. You need `if` instead of `while`:

```
a = list(1,2,3,4)

for(i in a){
  if(i != 2){
    print(i)
  }
}
```

Comment: I should have stated more clearly, I am looking for an answer that works with a while loop, my apologies. Edited the question

Comment: Then specify what needs to happen inside the `while` loop. If `i` equals 1, you have an infinite `while` loop.